# IE CSS issue, submenu navigation doesn't appear

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with drop-down navigation in IE. The link to webpage is as follows. Sub-menu doesn't appear at all in IE,  however in rest of the browser it is working fine.

http://www.careerheartedspirit.com

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO! I do think you need to improve your question a bit. For example: have you tried to narrow down the problem yet? What solutions have you tried so far? Which versions of IE display this behavior? Also have a look at the [w3 validator results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.careerheartedspirit.com), you have 125 errors in your markup.

Comment: I have tested it in IE8, IE9 & even in IE9 compatibility mode, it doesn't work. But in other browsers i.e. Firefox, Safari & Chrome, it is working fine. So I don't think whether my markup is causing problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue I can see, is caused by putting the code below before your `DOCTYPE`. It causes IE to go into **quirks** mode instead of **standards** mode. If there is something, even a comment, before the `DOCTYPE` then Internet Explorer will trigger quirks mode.:

```
<style>
    .log a:hover {
        color:#434343;
    }
</style>
```

Move the code inside of the `<head>` section to stop IE from going into quirks mode.

Comment: I have moved the code inside of the head tag but the problem is still there. Any other solution is appreciated...

Comment: The code is still above the `DOCTYPE` on the site. This solution should fix it. EDIT: Just seen you have now changed the code and the site is now working properly in IE. Please don't forget to accept the answer by marking the tick to the left of the answer and under the arrows.

Comment: @user1344823 clear your cache, page looks fine for me in IE7 and 8.